# Notification Emails Using Mailchimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailchimp

I am new to mailing with webapps. I looked around and found Sendgrid and Mailchimp. I can see that sendgrid's developer section has a simple smtp url that i should be able to use simply. However i don't find any such thing on Mailchimp. I am wondering how I can use mailchimp to send notifications like User registration or confirmation notification (not necessarily large number of emails blasted altogether but individual notification emails). Right now my application is set to use sendmail in rails.

Can anyone give me clues as to how I can use Mailchimp as the service for sending notification like emails and not mass emails. So far it seems like mailchimp may be more for just mass emails, is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: Just an advise: have a look at Madmimi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendgrid is a simple SMTP provider and relay. Mailchimp is more designed for email marketing using their toolchain. I would reccomend that you stick with sendgrid for simple notification messages but use Mailchimp for email campaigns and complex notifications.

So yes you initial guess is correct that it the two services are to be used for different things. However if you really want to use Mailchimp for email notificatons I would be more than happy to dig up some information for you.

Comment: Thanks Devin! Mailchimp looked really slick, but I am going to just stick to Sendgrid for notifications (waiting for them to approve my account)